# Falla Jasper Report al cargar proyecto en otro equipo

Tags: netbeans, jasper-reports

**Estimados**

Cambié de equipo y cargué un proyecto en netbeans el cual tenia unos reportes diseñados y listos en jasper report, el problema es que ahora cuando voy al designer no me muestra el diseño, sino que solo puedo ver el xml
y7 al ejecutar la aplicación, los reportes tienen fallas.
Que puedo hacer?
Ya cargue el jasper nuevamente en el netbeans pero nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero, pues, los `.jasper` son los binarios que generas al compilar el reporte. Para editarlos, necesitas los `.jrxml`

Comment: si pero el jrxml no funciona . antes aparecia el diseño y podia modificar el diseño del reporte. ahora no. solo se muestra el xml

Comment: Cuando dices que cargaste jasper de nuevo es que instalaste el plugin correspondiente? Qué versión del plugin y qué versión de netbeans?

Comment: si el mismo, pero no reconoce el diseño , es como si no tuviese el jasper

Comment: Versión de netbeans????

Comment: Versión de netbean 7.4

Comment: @SimónPereiraVigouroux lo que hago es abrirlo en jasper y si actualiza pero hay que compilar el proyecto

Comment: si pero no se me muestra la vista de diseño de jasper, sólo se ve tal cual está por lo tanto no puedo compilar el reporte

Comment: No tengo las opciones de editar el reporte , solo tengo el xml , no puedo ver ni modificar el diseño de mis reportes

Comment: hola ya corregir mi problea , era la version del plugin jasper report.